# Wipe Firebase data which not belong to owner

Tags: firebase

I'm not sure this is a security bug or something wrong in firefeed.firebaseio.com rules setting.

Before this, I'm curious why we don't get api-key when we register firebase.
so my first question come out. (Everyone can simple wipe or edit your data? if someone know your firebase url)

Then i want to know how rules works and i tried something on `firefeed.firebaseio.com`. Since we can write something in `users/user_id/feed` and I use this code to write into feed.

```
var url = new Firebase('https://firefeed.firebaseIO.com');
    var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(url, function(error, user) {
        if (error) {

            console.log(error);

        } else if (user) {

            console.log(user);
            // user authenticated with Firebase
            var usersRef = url.child('/users/MYUSERID/feed');
            usersRef
                .set({
                        email: user.email,
                        username: user.username
                    });
        } else {
            // user is logged out
        }
    });
```

After that all my feeds and following feeds are gone and only left email, username after I run my code. I attached a after and before picture here.

I know i am just wipe my account feeds not others since the rules have set spoof-user but is this dangerous? how we can prevent this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security rules currently allow you to delete your own feed, as per this line: https://github.com/firebase/firefeed/blob/master/rules.json#L14

```
// The user is allowed to write everything in their bucket.
".write": "$userid == auth.id"
```

You can change this behavior by removing that line from the security rules for Firefeed (on your own deployment of course, we do not intend on changing this behavior for the public version on firefeed.io).